# drop_First=true during dummy variable creation in pandas

Tags: python, linear-regression

I have months(Jan, Feb, Mar etc) data in my dataset and I am generating dummy variable using pandas library.
pd.get_dummies(df['month'],drop_first=True)

I want to understand whether I should use drop_first=True or not in this case?
Why is it important to use drop_first and for which type of variables?

Comment: yes you should, imagine you are looking at a coin flip, and have a feature called is_head, you do not need a column is_tail because you already know it via is_head=False. Same applies to other features like your month, if jan to nov are false it is clear that it is december. Why is that important? Because more dummy features make it harder for the algorithm to fit or even worse make it easier to overfit.

Answer (score 18):

- drop_first=True is important to use,  as it helps in reducing the extra column created during dummy variable creation. Hence it reduces the correlations created among dummy variables.
- Let’s say we have 3 types of values in Categorical column and we want to create dummy variable for that column.  If one variable is not furnished and semi_furnished, then It is obvious unfurnished. So we do not need 3rd variable to identify the unfurnished.
  [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMWkQ.png)

Hence if we have  categorical variable with n-levels, then we need to use n-1 columns to represent the dummy variables.

Comment: This should have been the default IMO

Comment: Let's imagine that "unfurnished" is actually a very important feature in the model. How would I know this? Because I remove unfurnished as per your example above. Yes we can still tell what row is unfurnished looking at your data, but for example if you plot the feature importances after model building, unfurnished will not appear there, even though it is an important feature. How does this work?

Comment: if we have 3 levels (unknown, True, False) in the column. How can I tell python not only to drop_first but also drop exactly the 'unknown' column?

Comment: @AmanBagrecha makes a good point.  If `drop_first=True` is so important in reducing the dimensionality, shouldn't it be the default setting for the `get_dummies()` function?

When would it be appropriate to eve set `drop_first=False`?

Answer (score 4):

**What is `drop_first=True`**

`drop_first=True` drops the first column during dummy variable creation. Suppose, you have a column for gender that contains 4 variables- "Male", "Female", "Other", "Unknown". So a person is either "Male", or "Female", or "Other". If they are not either of these 3, their gender is "Unknown".

**We do NOT need another column for "Uknown".**

It can be necessary for some situations, while not applicable for others. The goal is to reduce the number of columns by dropping the column that is not necessary. However, it is not always true. For some situations, we need to keep the first column.

**Example**

Suppose, we have 5 unique values in a column called "Fav_genre"- "Rock", "Hip hop", "Pop", "Metal", "Country" This column contains value
While dummy variable creation, we usually generate 5 columns. In this case,  `drop_first=True` is not applicable. A person may have more than one favorite genres. So dropping any of the columns would not be right. Hence, `drop_first=False` is the default parameter.

Answer (score 0):

- What

one hot encoding: it is a technique which converts categorical data into a form which is understandable by ml model.

- How

for eg: If there is a column which has 10 unique categorical values or labels, using pd.getdummies() we convert them into a binary
vector which makes 10 columns, one column for each unique value of our original column and wherever this value is true for a row it is indicated as 1 else 0.

- what

if drop_first is true it removes the first column which is created for the first unique value of a column.

In our case it will be 9 columns not 10 columns.

- how

It useful bcoz it reduces the number columns, here is how, when all the other columns are zero that means the first columns is 1.

refer this to know better:
https://www.dataindependent.com/pandas/pandas-get-dummies/